# Master-Detail: UINavigatorController vs Storyboard Segue

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, master-detail

**Scenario:** Master(TableView) --> Detail. 
**Modus Operandi:** Select Row --> display DetailVC

As you can see below, I have a `MasterVC` embedded in a `UINavigationController`:

[image]

I currently display the DetailVC via pushing it into the UINavigationController's VC stack:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Bliss", bundle: nil);
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DiaryPlayerVC") as DiaryPlayerViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

This works fine. 
However, the 'prepareForSeque' doesn't fire:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDiaryPlayer" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
                let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
//                (segue.destinationViewController as DiaryPlayerViewController).detailItem = object
            }
        }
    }
```

I understand that I probably have two (2) conflicting paradigms here:

1) Using the UINavigationController vs
2) Using the Storyboard Relationship.

So... 
**Option 1**: it appears that I can remove the Segue link to have a storyboard stand-alone `DetailVC`.

**Option 2**: via Segue, I'm assuming I can remove the `UINavigatorController` from the link.

I'm currently using Option #1, launching the `DetailVC` via the `UINavigationController`.

**Question:** If I choose Option #2, how do I access (launch) the `DetailVC` ("Diary Player") from the Master's Row and hence, fire the Segue's `'prepareForSegue()'`?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: create a segue from the table view cell to the detail view controller.

Comment: How do I trigger the segue from the master table's row?

Comment: Right-click and drag from the table view cell to the detail view controller in the storyboard. Then anytime a table view cell is tapped, it will segue to the detail view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows that you already created a segue in your storyboard. Give that segue an identifier in its property inspectory. Then you can simply perform the segue in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath")
    performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Note: Ctrl-drag the segue from the TableViewController icon, not from the TableViewCell.